# C++: написать функцию, которая для заданного числа х печатает количество пар(расположенных последовательно) одинаковых битов

Tags: c++

Я первый раз работаю с побитовыми операциями и не могу разобраться что я делаю не так, вроде по логике должно работать, но не работает. Тип числа должен быть беззнаковым.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int Count(unsigned a)
{
    int counter = 0, i = 0;
    unsigned k = a >> 1;

    while (++i != 8)
    {
        if (!(a ^ k))
            counter++;
        a >>= 1;
    }
    return counter;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned digit;
    do {
        cin >> digit;
    } while (digit > 65535 || digit < 0);
    cout << bitset<sizeof(unsigned int) * 2>(digit) << endl;
    unsigned k = digit >>= 1;
    cout << Count(digit);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Чтоб лучше понять... в числе 0 - сколько таких пар?

Comment: В числе 0 - 0 пар, в числе 12, которое в двоичной 00001100 - 5 пар.

Comment: Вообще, 12 в двоичной системе - 1100, а 00001100 - это значение содержимое байта, в который записали число 12.... Ну так, на всякий случай. Вдруг это окажется важным. Потому как в виде байта 0 это 00000000 и пар там будет никак не 0.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, действительно пар будет 7.

Comment: Вы бы уточнили где-то, какое представление Вам нужно. Потому что если речь именно о числе, а не о содержащем его байте (что лично мне показалось бы правильнее) то в 0 - 0пар, а в 12 -две пары. Тем более, что если говорить о представлении числа в памяти... А какая система используется? Сколько бит занимает число? 8, 16, 32 или 64?

Comment: Так 0 - это 00000000, 0000000000000000 или 00000000000000000000000000000000?...

Comment: В задании говорится о числе, но я подумал про байт который содержит это число, тогда да, учитываются только значащие нули.

Comment: 8 бит будет достаточно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, раз вы используете `bitset`, значит, это в рамках задания. Раз вы не знаете точно представление числа - значит, придется использовать шаблон...

```
template<typename Int>
int pairs(Int n)
{
    static_assert(is_integral_v<Int> && is_unsigned_v<Int>);
    constexpr int bits = sizeof(Int)*8;
    bitset<bits> b(n);
    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < bits; ++i)
        p += (b[i] == b[i-1]);
    return p;
}
```

Это годится? Полный код (опущенный :) до С++14) - тут: https://ideone.com/ivWJ6x

Не устраивает `bitset`? Без проблем:

```
template<typename Int>
int pairs(Int n)
{
    static_assert(is_integral_v<Int> && is_unsigned_v<Int>);
    constexpr int bits = sizeof(Int)*8;
    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < bits; ++i)
        p += (((n>>i)&1) == ((n>>(i-1))&1));
    return p;
}
```

Надо именно для байта? Опять же проще простого...

```
int bytePairs(unsigned char n)
{
    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 8; ++i)
        p += (((n>>i)&1) == ((n>>(i-1))&1));
    return p;
}
```

Для особо ленивых, не желающих думать самостоятельно, отбрасываем ведущие нули.

```
int bytePairs(unsigned char n)
{
    int p = 0, i = 7;
    if (n < 3) return 0;
    for(;!(n>>i);--i);
    for(; i > 0; --i)
        p += (((n>>i)&1) == ((n>>(i-1))&1));
    return p;
}
```

Куда приезжать мыть полы?...

Comment: bitset я использую так как мне нужно видеть число с которым я работаю, в окончательном виде мне нужно вывести только количество пар.

Comment: А я что вывожу? Функция и возвращает число пар.

Comment: А можно как-то для 8 битного числа откинуть незначащие 0 и считать пары только значащих цифр?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: Не судите строго, у меня 1 семестр С++ и первая лабораторная по побитовым операциям.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Жаль, нельзя второй раз плюсануть ответ...